# How to go about debugging HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, api, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to connect a java application to an external api for GuildWars2.

The link I am trying to test is:
http://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings

A list of int IDs are returned when navigating to that page within a browser.

As a learning practice, I am trying to get that list of id's when running my java application.

I use the following code (hopefully it formats correct, currently on my phone, trying to program remotely to my desktop):

```
public class GuildWarsAPI
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GuildWarsAPI api = new GuildWarsAPI();
        api.getAPIResponse("http://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings");
    }

    public void getAPIResponse(String URLString)
    {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(URLString);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (connection != null)
            {
                System.out.println("connection success");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
               try {
                 /*BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                 StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
                    String nextLine = null;
                    while ((nextLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("adding output");
                        input.append(nextLine);
                    }*/
                   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                   int b = 0;
                   while ((b = in.read()) != -1)
                   {
                       System.out.println("byte:" + b);
                   }
                   System.out.println("done");
               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               finally {
                 connection.disconnect();
                 System.out.println("closed");
               }
            }
    }
}
```

Upon running my class, it immediately prints out `connection success`, `done`, `closed`. It definitely isnt waiting for the timeouts, and i've been trying to play with that, the request header, and the DoInput/DoOutput. I stepped through it, and it appears as if it connects, and just doesnt receive any bytes of information back. (doesnt go into the `while` loop)

So, while my ultimate question is: How do I get the id's back like I expect?, my other question is: how can I figure out how to get the other id's back like I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code is getting response code `302 Found`. It should follow the `Location:` header to the new location, as `followRedirects` is true by default, but it isn't. The server is however returning a `Location:` header of `https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings`. I don't know why `HttpURLConnection` isn't following that, but the simple fix is to use `https:` in the original URL.
2. You're setting `doOutput(true)` but you aren't sending any output.
3. Your code is poorly structured. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that same `try` block. I would have the method *throw* `MalformedURLException` and `IOException` and not have any internal `try/catch` blocks at all.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you don't mind - how did you determine the response code and header leading to a different location?

Comment: Via `connection.getResponseCode()`, and then `connection.getHeaderField("Location")` after I had seen the 302.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, wrestling with `HttpUrlConnection` is more trouble than it's worth.

It's hard to debug, hard to use, and provides very little support for complex http operations.

There are a bunch of better options.

My default choice is Apache HttpConponents Client (http://hc.apache.org/). It's not necessarily any better than all the other options, but it's quite well documented and widely used.

Comment: This is not a 'complex HTTP operation'. `HttpURLConnection` has been working for me for 20 years. The only time I've had to shift to the Apache client was when I wanted to send WEBDAV verbs